# Initial First Name Last Name

Tags: initialisms

Is it acceptable to put your first name initial followed by last name in a written document.

For example, if the name is John Smith to say J. Smith? Is it appropriate?

Comment: This depends on the document, its audience, purpose and formality, none of which are defined in your question. In general, the convention is to use the full first name, however nothing technically prevents an author being credited as "Initial + surname"

Comment: The document is a blog post, the audience is anyone, and formality would be business professional.

Comment: This is a style enquiry, better asked over on Writing.SE.

Comment: I agree with kaipmdh above. **"It depends on the document."**